# Is this a good reply to "Take care"

Tags: usage

Does the reply "Take care, you too." to "Take care." makes sense?

Comment: You could just say: *"Thanks. You too."*

Answer (score 2):

"You too!" is a possible reply, or "You take care too!"  Your reply includes the subject "you" but it is not in the right place.

Since "Take care" would normally be said *to* someone who is departing *by* someone who is staying, it might not always be appropriate to say "you too". Instead "Thanks" or "Thanks, I will", or "Will do" may be better replies. Or perhaps "Thanks, bye." There is no particular reply that is more common.

Answer (score 1):

To say 'take care' to someone on leaving their company is really a way of showing affection or politeness. It is perfectly normal for one person to say 'take care' and the other to reply e.g. 'Yes, I will. You take care too.'. Either a departing or remaining person can start the exchange. **There is no rule**.